# Request.JS and Node.js Data problems

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node and I am developing an app that uses Request.JS to pull data from a private API.  I need the data to be displayed in one of my views.  Currently I have Request being required and defined in one of my routes, like so:

```
var models  = require('../models');// Required for sequelize
var express = require('express');// Required for the Express framework
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');// For requesting API data

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        request( // Request from API
        'http://PrivateAPI.com:8080/reports/22?type=0&key=privatekey', 
        function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body) // Print the return of the api call.
        }
      })
    models.User.findAll({ // $$$-Define User DB call. 
      }).then(function(users) {
    res.render('index', { 
      title: 'Project Insight',
      users: users,
      request: request
    });
  });
})
```

When this runs, I can see the output of the data in my console, but I wanted to know the best way to have it display in one of my views.  Also, should I even have this in my route?  Am lost, thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to write your index view that takes the response from that private service. What template rendering engine are you using?

Comment: EJS (Embedded Javascript)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the current code has some resource dependency issues, since the response from the private API might not be available at the time of render. I have simply moved the database call and succeeding operations to the private service request handler. For the actual answer: it's as simple as passing more data to the rendering operation:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  request( // Request from API
      'http://PrivateAPI.com:8080/reports/22?type=0&key=privatekey', 
      function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(body);
          // response ok, continuing
          models.User.findAll({ // $$$-Define User DB call. 
            }).then(function(users) {
          res.render('index', { 
            title: 'Project Insight',
            users: users,
            request: request,
            body: body // <--
          });
        } else {
          // handle error
        }
      });
});
```

In your view/index.ejs, simply use the variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  ...
  Using <%= body %>, properties are also available if applicable ( <%= body.attr1 %>, <%= body.attr2 %>, ...) 
  ...
</html>
```